# Insert Multiple values by not updating column in sql server using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, insert

I would like to know is there a way to insert values to the same column without updating the same value.

This is my table structure

```
Column Name Data Type Allow Nulls
----------- --------- ------------
Expiry Date Date       No
```

Now I would like to insert multiple date values in the Expiry Date. So how do I do that?

So that my output should be as follows:

```
Expiry Date

23/3/2014,23/4/2014,23/5/2015
```

This is my insert Statement

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Customers (UserID, Validity, Amount, RegisteredDate, 
ExpiryDate, FirstName, LastName, Address, State, City, Phone, Mobile, Email) 
VALUES(@UserID,@Validity,@Amount,@RegisteredDate,@ExpiryDate,@FirstName,@LastName,
@Address,@State,@City,@Phone,@Mobile,@Email)"
```

This is my Update Statement:

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Customers SET  UserID = @UserID, Validity = @Validity, 
Amount = @Amount, RegisteredDate = @RegisteredDate, ExpiryDate = @ExpiryDate,
FirstName   = @FirstName, LastName = @LastName , Address = @Address, State = @State, 
City = @City, Phone = @Phone, Mobile= @Mobile, Email = @Email WHERE UserID = @UserID"
```

Comment: you can't date data type can only hold date data.  comma seperated strings are not valid dates.  Might be possible if you're doing tables within tables; but i never saw the point in this yet.

Answer (score 1):

If your ExpiryDate is defined in the database as a date field then the answer is you can't do that. However, if it defined as a string (which it should never be) then you can just concatenate the multiple expiry dates and store it as you would any other string. But I don't see how multiple expiry dates makes sense. But if, for some reason that isn't obvious multiple dates are valid **and** you want them stored as dates then you could define a separate table of expiry dates and store an ExpiryDateID in the first table and have a one-to-many relationship between the existing table and the new one.